# MalformedByteSequenceException creating xsd file with xml file

Tags: java, xerces

i have one xml file. While I need to create xsd file for that xml file through trang in  command prompt. I got error

> fatal: exception
>   "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequen
>
> ceException" thrown: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

my xml file is

```
<Geography> 
    <Country name="Afghanistan" id="2001" shortname="AFG"></Country>
    <Country name="Albania" id="2002" shortname="ALB"></Country>
    <Country name="Algeria" id="2003" shortname="DZA"></Country>
</Geography>
```

please give me a solution.

Comment: Look at the XML with hex viewer and see if there are any unexpected chars there (for the above, valid ones are printable chars 20..7E and 0A for LF, possibly 0D for CR and 09 for TAB). Maybe there's BOM marker at the start, and xerces can't handle it in UTF-8?

Comment: Another possiblity: file is actually UTF-16 or something, not UTF-8 at all.

Comment: \country.xml:1:57: fatal: Content is not allowed in prolog. I got this exception in command prompt

Comment: If that :1:57 means line and column, it does not match the XML shown in question, there line 1 is shorter than that...

Comment: Actually i changed <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>.on that time only i got this error country.xml:1:57: fatal: Content is not allowed in prolog.If i using utf-8 means i got this error  :fatal: exception "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequen
ceException" thrown: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: Ok. 1. Forget about UTF16. 2. Question doesn't show any XML prolog, please [edit] it to be accurate. 3. Test after Re-saving the XML file with some editor which allows setting encoding, and use UTF8 without BOM.